# mostrar select option correcto cuando se le pasa un id mediante jQuery?

Tags: javascript, mysqli, php7

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de alta baja y modificación de un catalogo de productos.
No logro que el select me muestre la opción que le paso por medio de un id cuyo valor esta dentro del boton editar.

Código de botón

```
<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary lapiz\" data-descr3=\"$marca_sub\" data- 
descr2=\"$nombre_sub\" data-descr1=\"$categoria\" data-descr=\"$id_sub\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data- 
target=\".editar\"><i class=\"fas fa-pen\"></i></button>
```

esto abre un modal cuyo código es:

```
<div class="modal fade editar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria- 
hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar Sub Categoría</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
  </div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form action="bm.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="id_cat1" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="width: 100%">Categoría</label>
<select name="categoria1" id="categoria1" style="width: 100%">
<option>Seleccionar</option>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM categoria";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$id = $row['id_cat'];
$categoria = $row['nombre_cat'];
echo"
<option value=\"$id\">$categoria</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>
</div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="width: 100%">Sub Categoría</label>
            <input name="scategoria1" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="width: 100%">Marca</label>
            <input name="marca1" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
            </div>
        <div class="form-group mt-5">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Editar" name="btnEditar">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Borrar">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

y el scripts es este

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.lapiz', function () {
    var descr = $(this).attr('data-descr');
    var descr1 = $(this).attr('data-descr1');
    var descr2 = $(this).attr('data-descr2');
    var descr3 = $(this).attr('data-descr3');
    $('.editar input[name=id_cat1]').val(descr);
    $('.editar input[name=categoria1]').val(descr1);
    $('.editar input[name=scategoria1]').val(descr2);
    $('.editar input[name=marca1]').val(descr3);
    $('.editar #categoria1').puidropdown('selectValue', descr);
    $('.editar').showModal(); // o similar
});
</script>
```

Mediante este script logro pasar todas las variables pero no logro que el select entienda la variable descr que seria el id y me muestre esa categoría.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Has depurado algo, por ejemplo: `console.log(descr);` ? ¿El problema es sólo con esa variable? ¿Verificaste con  `var_dump($id_sub);` si la variable del id tiene datos? Cuéntanos todas las depuraciones que has hecho y con qué resultados.

Comment: las variables al modal se pasan bien, lo que no logro es que el select, cuando le mando la variable 1, me muestre la opción 1 del mismo. El tema está en el scripts que no se como hacerlo , porque en el campo input que recibe el id lo muestra perfecto, pero el select no muestra la opción correspondiente a esa id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el script tienes que mostrar el modal primero y despues setear el select...

```
$('.editar').showModal();

//el timeout se necesita para asegurar que la funcion se dispare despues de que modal aparesca
setTimeout(() => {
  $('#categoria1').val(descr);
}, 100)
```

Comment: Martin gracias por tu ayuda, pero no me funciona, solo lo hace cuando elegís el primer registro , me muestra bien que son remeras, pero al hacer click en el segundo registro, aparece el select vacio y si lo desplegas salen todas las opciones.

Comment: si intentas hacer 'let elems = $('#categoria1'); console.log(elems)' cuantos elementos te regresa la segunda vez que haces click?

Comment: espero haberlo hecho bien, soy nuevo en esto de js 
Da como resultado la consola 
S.fn.init [select#categoria1]
0: select#categoria1
0: option
1: option
2: option

Comment: Martín: No quería dejar pasar que tu solución funcionó, el tonto era yo que le pasaba el id de subcategoría y no el de categoría. Muchas Gracias Por tu ayuda. Un Abrazo

Comment: Alejandro, me alegra que te funciono. Saludos.